# REGEX: select everything to the left until the first specified delimeter

Tags: regex, coldfusion, regex-lookarounds, ldap-query

I'm using ColdFusion functions to query an Active Directory Database, return Membership information for a user, then REGEX functions to search the output for specified groups.  I made "|" a delimiter.

**Anyway, here's some example output:**

```
CN=Group One,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Group Two,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Group Three,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Group Four,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Group Five,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org
```

**What I would like to capture is this:**

CN=Group Three,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

```
^|CN=(.*Group? Three)
```

*Here's a link to the example:  http://rubular.com/r/DIGZOPwTag*

**What's my problem?**

Well, this doesn't work all that great... It goes to the left, but it goes too far!  How do I stop it at the first occurrence of **|CN=** to the left?

Thank you in advance for your time.  It is appreciated.

---

### **!!Clarification!!**

**Better Example Output:**

```
CN=Pay Band 50,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Human Resources,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=SiteA Staff,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=SiteB Additional Staff,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org|CN=Executives,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Domain,DC=org
```

**Desired matches:**

I'm looking for specific groups:

1. *Site Name w/Possible Spaces* **Staff**
2. *Site Name w/Possible Spaces* **Additional Staff**

It would be awesome to return:  "StieAlpha Staff", "Site Beta Additional Staff".  It would also be acceptable to include the "CN=" prefix because I could use it to do queries later.

"**Staff**" and "**Additional Staff**" will always be part of the group(s) I want to match.

**What I've tried, again**

```
^|CN=[^|CN=]*? Staff|Additional? Staff
```

This new example is not quite perfect as it doesn't grab all of "Site Beta".  "Site Beta" Could be any name of any building, for example.

example link:  http://rubular.com/r/vq5JcrvaBR

Comment: From "ironsider's" comments below, I think this is the answer:

CN=([^,]* Staff)|CN=([^,]*Additional Staff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want to extract, if only the "Group Three" CN value or all CN values.
You can extract every CN value with this regex:

```
CN=([^,]*)
```

this regex begins extracting after each "CN=" occurence and continues extraction until the first comma (,).

Comment: It won't let me vote you up because I don't have '15' for a reputation yet.  This is quite beautiful.  I have added better clarification & examples to my post.

Comment: I don't understand the answer but I have sufficient rep to vote on @user3772763's behalf.

Comment: I think this should be the answer... it got me in the right direction: 

CN=([^,]* Staff)|CN=([^,]*Additional Staff)

Comment: yes you are right, you can put static strings inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

A RegEx to fit your demands is
`^.*?\|`. Visualisation:

[image]